# Have an invalidinput error when I tried to communicate nodemcu with arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to send multiple data from Arduino to nodemcu. But it keeps showing error

**deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput**

here is the code

**Arduino UNO**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <ArduinoJson.h>

SoftwareSerial s(5,6);

void setup() {

s.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

StaticJsonDocument<1000> doc;

doc["data1"] = 100;

doc["data2"] = 200;

serializeJson(doc,s);
delay(1000);

}
```

**nodemcu**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial s(D6,D5);
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

}

void loop() {
  StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
  while(s.available()){
    //delay(1000);
    Serial.write(s.read());
    auto error = deserializeJson(doc,s);
    if(error) {
      Serial.println();
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed with code "));
        Serial.println(error.c_str());
    }
    serializeJsonPretty(doc,Serial);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

and here is the result

```
{

deserializeJson() failed with code IncompleteInput

false"

deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

null:

deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

100"

deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

null:

deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

200{

deserializeJson() failed with code IncompleteInput

false"

deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

null:

deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput
```

Comment: remove `Serial.write(s.read());`

Comment: It still only works sometimes. But most of the time the same error happened.

Comment: remove the `delay(1000);`

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still the same result

Comment: and know you must somehow synchronize them. for start put a 5 seconds delay as last line in  setup() in Uno

Comment: It only works sometimes, Most of the times are showing the deserializeJson() failed with code InvalidInput

Answer (score 0):

The page [How to do serial communication between two boards?](https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/do-serial-communication-between-two-boards/) says that [InvalidInput](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/misc/deserializationerror/) is due to either:

- clock skew
- bad wiring / electric noise
- receiver reading too slowly and dropping bytes
- voltage mismatch (5V vs. 3.3V)

You cannot do anything for clock skew except using the same MCU on both sides.

It would be best if you increased the speed of the "debugging" serial port. It must be an order of magnitude faster than the "transmission" serial port.

You can fix voltage mismatch with a [logic level converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NAY2BBY).